# .NET Core MVC, Data keeps freezing even when set as transient

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc

Orginally I thought this issue was being caused by a singleton, but I have this problem even when my dependency is set to transient as well. All my code is doing is reading a csv file and mapping it to an object as seen here:

```
public class CallStatReports
{


    string homeServer = @"\\10.XX.XX.XXX\Reports";
    string csvName = "helpdeskCallStats.csv";
    private int attempts;

    public CallStats TennesseeCallStats { get; set; }
    public CallStats FloridaCallStats { get; set; }

    public CallStats CorporateCallStats { get; set; }
    public CallStats CRCCallStats { get; set; }

    public void RefreshStats()
    {
        var filePath = Path.Combine(homeServer, csvName);

        using (var fileReader = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(fileReader))
            {
                var cReader = new CsvReader(reader);


                cReader.Configuration.Delimiter = ":";
                cReader.Configuration.ReadingExceptionOccurred = null;
                cReader.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<CallStatsMapper>();

                var results = cReader.GetRecords<CallStats>().ToArray();

                //Sometimes the stream will be empty, so this recursively calls itself until it hits 20 attempts and then returns
                if (results.Count() == 0 && attempts++ <= 20)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(5);
                    RefreshStats();
                    return;
                }


                TennesseeCallStats = results.FirstOrDefault(x => x.SplitSkill == "Tenn E Emergent");
                FloridaCallStats = results.FirstOrDefault(x => x.SplitSkill == "FL Emergent");
                CorporateCallStats = results.FirstOrDefault(x => x.SplitSkill == "s_68_Corp Users");
                CRCCallStats = results.FirstOrDefault(x => x.SplitSkill == "s_1 Help Desk");

            }
        }
    }

}


public class CallStats
{
    public CallStats()
    {
        SplitSkill = string.Empty;
        SkillState = string.Empty;
        AgentsStaffed = default(int);
        CallsWaiting = default(int);
        OldestCallWaiting = default(TimeSpan);
        ACDCalls = default(int);
        AvgACDTime = default(TimeSpan);
        AbanCalls = default(int);
        AvgAbanTime = default(TimeSpan);
        AvgSpeedAns = default(TimeSpan);

    }

    public string SplitSkill { get; set; }
    public string SkillState { get; set; }
    public int AgentsStaffed { get; set; }
    public int CallsWaiting { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan OldestCallWaiting { get; set; }
    public int ACDCalls { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan AvgACDTime { get; set; }
    public int AbanCalls { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan AvgAbanTime { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan AvgSpeedAns { get; set; }
}


public class AgentReports
{

    string homeServer = @"\\10.XX.XX.XXX\Reports";
    string csvName = "helpdesk.csv";
    private int attempts;

    public List<Agent> CorporateAgents
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public List<Agent> CRCAgents
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public List<Agent> TennesseeAgents
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public List<Agent> FloridaAgents
    {
        get;
        set;
    }


public void RefreshStats()
{
    var filePath = Path.Combine(homeServer, csvName);
    using (var fileReader = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(fileReader))
        {
            var cReader = new CsvReader(reader);
            cReader.Configuration.Delimiter = ":";
            cReader.Configuration.ReadingExceptionOccurred = null;

            var results = cReader.GetRecords<dynamic>().ToList();

                //Sometimes the stream returns no data, so it recursively calls itself unless the stream was empty 20 times in a row.
                if(results.Count == 0 && attempts++ <= 20)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(5);
                    RefreshStats();
                    return;
                }
            var convertedAgents = results.Select(x => new Agent()
            {
                AgentName = x.AgentName,
                Icon = int.Parse(x.Icon),
                State = x.State,
                AuxReason = x.AuxReason,
                Skills = new List<string>(((ExpandoObject)x).Where(y => y.Key.ToLower().Contains("skill")).Select(z => z.Value.ToString())),
                LoginID = x.LoginID,
                Time = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(double.Parse(x.Time))
            }).ToList();



            TennesseeAgents = convertedAgents.Where(x => x.Skills.Contains("Tenn E Emergent")).Distinct().ToList();
            FloridaAgents = convertedAgents.Where(x => x.Skills.Contains("FL Emergent")).Distinct().ToList();
            CRCAgents = convertedAgents.Where(x => x.Skills.Contains("s_1 Help Desk")).Distinct().ToList();
            CorporateAgents = convertedAgents.Where(x => x.Skills.Contains("s_68_Corp Users")).Distinct().ToList();

        }
    }

}
```

I then have a controller that takes a factory object with this data and displays it on a webpage....

```
public class DashboardController : Controller
{
    private DashboardFactory _dashFactory;

    public DashboardController(DashboardFactory dashFactory)
    {
        _dashFactory = dashFactory;
        _dashFactory.AgentReports.RefreshStats();
        _dashFactory.CallStatReports.RefreshStats();
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(_dashFactory);
    }

    public IActionResult TNAgentView()
    {

        return PartialView("DashView",_dashFactory.TennesseeAgents);
    }

    public IActionResult FLAgentView()
    {
        return PartialView("DashView",_dashFactory.FloridaAgents);
    }

    public IActionResult CorpAgentView()
    {
        return PartialView("DashView",_dashFactory.Corporate);
    }

    public IActionResult CRCAgentView()
    {
        return PartialView("DashView",_dashFactory.CRC);
    }


    public IActionResult CRC()
    {
        return View(_dashFactory.CRC);
    }

    public IActionResult Corporate()
    {
        return View(_dashFactory.Corporate);
    }

    public IActionResult AccessCenter()
    {
        return View(_dashFactory);
    }
}

public  class DashboardFactory
{


    private const int delayTime = 3;

    public DashboardFactory(AgentReports agentReports, CallStatReports callStatReports)
    {
        this.CallStatReports = callStatReports;
        this.AgentReports = agentReports;
        callStatReports.RefreshStats();
        agentReports.RefreshStats();
    }

    public DashModel Corporate
    {
        get
        {
            return new DashModel(AgentReports.CorporateAgents, CallStatReports.CorporateCallStats);
        }
    }

    public DashModel CRC
    {
        get
        {

            return new DashModel(AgentReports.CRCAgents, CallStatReports.CRCCallStats);

        }
    }

    public DashModel FloridaAgents
    {
        get
        {

            return new DashModel(AgentReports.FloridaAgents, CallStatReports.FloridaCallStats);
        }
    }

    public DashModel TennesseeAgents
    {
        get
        {
            return new DashModel(AgentReports.TennesseeAgents, CallStatReports.TennesseeCallStats);
        }
    }

    public CallStatReports CallStatReports { get; }

    public AgentReports AgentReports { get; }
}
```

The page updates fine via jquery on its own (the view refreshes every 3 seconds with setInterval), but eventually over time the website will run into an internal server error 500 when the data is being loaded.

Once it errors out **once**, the data freezes.
The CallStatReports object just repeats itself over and over, without updating. It's almost as if the same object is being used, even if it is marked for being transient when resolved from the container.

I cannot for the life of me figure out why this is happening.
When running the debugger, the debugger doesn't break on the part where the code returns error 500.

Comment: Start by writing all your exceptions to a log. Then you could check them without a breakpoint. I would recommend you to send to that log the full exception together with all the data you have about the request that caused it.

Comment: Why is your factory only used once in the constructor? If you don't use it as a factory, you could just inject the two Reports. That said, post your DI code if they come from a DI container.

Comment: Please post your DI configuration as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out this issue, and I hope nobody else has to go through the hell that I've had to for the past week trying to tackle this.

Apparently, if you're reading data from a share drive Windows caches the data in some way. I was able to replicate this bug by having a stream open 200 times a second.

After a few seconds, the stream would open with cached data even if the file was updated. It would only do this if you'd happen to have a file that rarely changed (like in my case, the amount of calls taken would slowly update)

Since I could replicate the bug in a few seconds as opposed to hours... I tried many things. Nothing appeared to work, until I decided to have the data on the local machine instead of trying to get it from a share drive remotely.

That **immediately** fixed the bug.

So to briefly explain how I fixed it, I essentially reversed the data export.
Instead of having my server query the share drive for the data, I configured my exporting to instead export the data directly to my server that was previously importing it via a share drive.

I'm not a Windows Guru, there's probably another way to fix this like purging share drive cache... but this worked for me.